# Where is the webmin port number stored?

Tags: port

I made a typo when changing webmin's port number; now, I don't know what it is. How can I change it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try editing the /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf

Comment: dont forget to restart webmin - `/etc/init.d/webmin restart` for linux machines

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get a port number you have configured:

```
netstat -teplnu | grep perl
```

Comment: or "netstat -teplnu | grep webmin" , really do not know what binary/script webmin is using.